# React/Jest function component testing

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

How can I write a test case for my function component which is having API call to return data on load? For example consider below code:

```
//List of tasKs and process tasK information
const TaskList = props => {

/**Function to load data on component initialization */
    useEffect(() => {
        getData(true);
    }, []);

 /**
     * Function to pull tasks from database
     * @param {filters} applyfilter 
     */
    const getData = async applyfilter => {
        try {
            let taskData = await service.getTasks()
            taskData.tasks = taskData.tasks.sort(GFG_sortFunction)
            let status_data = taskData.tasks.filter(values => {
                if (statuses.includes(values.status_id)) {
                    return true
                }
            })

            setData(status_data);
            setT_Data(taskData.tasks);
            setshowGenerateDPF(true);
            builtFilter(taskData.tasks);
            if ((selectedPlatforms.length !== 0 || selectedAssets.length !== 0 || selectedCategories.length !== 0 || selectedStatus.length !== 0) && applyfilter)
                FilterTasksData(selectedPlatforms, selectedAssets, selectedCategories, selectedStatus, taskData.tasks);
        }
        catch (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    };
 return (
        <>
            <Row>
                <div data-testid="tasklist" style={{ float: "left", padding: "0" }} className={[classes.taskList, "col-md-8"].join(' ')}>
                    <span style={{ float: "left" }}>
                        {tasks.length} Tasks </span>
</div>
</Row>
</>
}
```

I want to write unit test case for `getData` method. How can I do that?

Answer (score -1):

You would want to mock the response and the other functions (like **setData** for example)

Here is a random example of mocking a fetch request with "react testing library" that **renders div with test id that outputs text data from request**

```
import YourComponent from '../'
import React from 'react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import { render, waitForElement } from '@testing-library/react';

describe('59892259', () => {
  let originFetch;
  beforeEach(() => {
    originFetch = (global as any).fetch;
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    (global as any).fetch = originFetch;
  });
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const fakeResponse = { data: 'example data' };
    const mRes = { json: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(fakeResponse) };
    const mockedFetch = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(mRes as any);
    (global as any).fetch = mockedFetch;
    const { getByTestId } = render(<YourComponent />);
    const div = await waitForElement(() => getByTestId('test'));
    expect(div).toHaveTextContent('example data');
    expect(mockedFetch).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mRes.json).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

you can write up a test that will expect to see "{tasks.length} Tasks" span's text as anything you mock, just make sure to mock or import the global store(redux/mobx) or hooks in your testing env so you will be able to mock the method calls as well

Comment: I tried what you mentioned, but data is not getting bind to test. Here the response I got

`const { getByTestId } = render(<TaskList />);
    > 68 |         const div = await waitFor(() => getByTestId('tasklist'));
         |                           ^
      69 |         expect(div).toHaveTextContent('BARN-IS-BI-SBX-BSB: OS Patching');
      70 |         expect(mockedFetch).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      at waitForWrapper (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/wait-for.js:173:27)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/test/
`